# How to install and run Sensenet DMS Demo? Getting Error while starting

Tags: sensenet

I am trying to evaluate sensenet and running it in local machine with Visual studio. Iam not a developer and not able to understand the steps described in github page. can someone help to provide step by step procedure to access sensenet client and document management demo?

To Avoid all this difficulties I Also  tried to download sense net 6.5, but as codeplex page are archived iam not able to download the same. if any other links to download exist it will be helpful.

[Error Details DMS Demo Installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2595C.png)

[Detailed Error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leodo.png)

Comment: An NPM package is missing, you can try to add it manually with the ```npm i uglifyjs-webpack-plugin``` command

Answer (score 0):

An NPM package is missing, you can try to add it manually with the `npm i uglifyjs-webpack-plugin` command.

Comment: Thanks for the reply i had installed. But when i executing the start command 3 errors are coming. As i need to give more details iam adding the error details while starting in separate answer. Application got installed. But when i give start command following errors are coming.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply, i had installed.

Installed and tried following errors came

ERROR in ./node_modules/@date-io/date-fns/build/index.esm.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'date-fns/addDays' in 'D:\sn-dms-demo-master\sn-dms-demo-master\node_modules@date-io\date-fns\build'

ERROR in ./node_modules/@date-io/date-fns/build/index.esm.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'date-fns/addMonths' in 'D:\sn-dms-demo-master\sn-dms-demo-master\node_modules@date-io\date-fns\build'

ERROR in ./node_modules/@date-io/date-fns/build/index.esm.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'date-fns/addYears' in 'D:\sn-dms-demo-master\sn-dms-demo-master\node_modules@date-io\date-fns\build'

ERROR in ./node_modules/@date-io/date-fns/build/index.esm.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'date-fns/differenceInMilliseconds' in 'D:\sn-dms-demo-master\sn-dms-demo-master\node_modules@date-io\date-fns\build'

ERROR in ./node_modules/@date-io/date-fns/build/index.esm.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'date-fns/eachDayOfInterval' in 'D:\sn-dms-demo-master\sn-dms-demo-master\node_modules@date-io\date-fns\build'

ERROR in ./node_modules/@date-io/date-fns/build/index.esm.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'date-fns/endOfDay' in 'D:\sn-dms-demo-master\sn-dms-demo-master\node_modules@date-io\date-fns\build'
.
.
.
.
.

**at the end following are coming**

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@sensenet/controls-react/dist/viewcontrols/EditView.d.ts:4:8
    TS1192: Module '"D:/sn-dms-demo-master/sn-dms-demo-master/node_modules/@types/react/index"' has no default export.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@sensenet/controls-react/dist/viewcontrols/BrowseView.d.ts:4:8
    TS1192: Module '"D:/sn-dms-demo-master/sn-dms-demo-master/node_modules/@types/react/index"' has no default export.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@sensenet/controls-react/dist/viewcontrols/NewView.d.ts:1:8
    TS1192: Module '"D:/sn-dms-demo-master/sn-dms-demo-master/node_modules/@types/react/index"' has no default export.
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
     1 asset
    Entrypoint undefined = index.html
    [./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./public/index.html] 2.22 KiB {0} [built]
    [./node_modules/lodash/lodash.js] 527 KiB {0} [built]
    [./node_modules/webpack/buildin/global.js] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 472 bytes {0} [built]
    [./node_modules/webpack/buildin/module.js] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 497 bytes {0} [built]
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.